# What is the best way to create a block matrix form a row vector?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, convolution

I have the following numpy row matrix.

```
X = np.array([1,2,3])
```

I want to create a block matrix as follows:

```
1 0 0
2 1 0
3 2 1
0 3 2
0 0 3
```

How can I do this using numpy?

Comment: What's the relationship of these two? Convolution?

Comment: Is the last element (row-5, col-3) really `1`?

Comment: Perhaps try https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.roll.html

Comment: @WendingPeng I am trying convolution through matrix method manually. I need to create a block matrix with one row.

Comment: @Divakar That was a mistake. I have corrected it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Approach #1 :** Using [`np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided`](http://www.scipy-lectures.org/advanced/advanced_numpy/#indexing-scheme-strides) -

```
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import as_strided as strided

def zeropad_arr_v1(X):
    n = len(X)
    z = np.zeros(len(X)-1,dtype=X.dtype)
    X_ext = np.concatenate(( z, X, z))

    s = X_ext.strides[0]
    return strided(X_ext[n-1:], (2*n-1,n), (s,-s), writeable=False)
```

Note that this would create a `read-only` output. If you need to write into later on, simply make a copy by appending `.copy()` at the end.

**Approach #2 :** Using concatenation with zeros and then clipping/slicing -

```
def zeropad_arr_v2(X):
    n = len(X)
    X_ext = np.concatenate((X, np.zeros(n,dtype=X.dtype)))
    return np.tile(X_ext, n)[:-n].reshape(-1,n,order='F')
```

Approach #1 being a strides-based method should be very efficient on performance.

Sample runs -

```
In [559]: X = np.array([1,2,3])

In [560]: zeropad_arr_v1(X)
Out[560]: 
array([[1, 0, 0],
       [2, 1, 0],
       [3, 2, 1],
       [0, 3, 2],
       [0, 0, 3]])

In [561]: zeropad_arr_v2(X)
Out[561]: 
array([[1, 0, 0],
       [2, 1, 0],
       [3, 2, 1],
       [0, 3, 2],
       [0, 0, 3]])
```

**Runtime test**

```
In [611]: X = np.random.randint(0,9,(1000))

# Approach #1 (read-only)
In [612]: %timeit zeropad_arr_v1(X)
100000 loops, best of 3: 8.74 µs per loop

# Approach #1 (writable)
In [613]: %timeit zeropad_arr_v1(X).copy()
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.05 ms per loop

# Approach #2
In [614]: %timeit zeropad_arr_v2(X)
1000 loops, best of 3: 705 µs per loop

# @user8153's solution
In [615]: %timeit hstack_app(X)
100 loops, best of 3: 2.26 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 2):

If you read the desired output matrix top-down, then left-right, you see the pattern 1,2,3, 0,0,0, 1,2,3, 0,0,0, 1,2,3. You can use that pattern to easily create a linear array, and then reshape it into the two-dimensional form:

```
import numpy as np
X = np.array([1,2,3])
N = len(X)
zeros = np.zeros_like(X)
m = np.hstack((np.tile(np.hstack((X,zeros)),N-1),X)).reshape(N,-1).T
print m
```

gives

```
[[1 0 0]
 [2 1 0]
 [3 2 1]
 [0 3 2]
 [0 0 3]]
```

Answer (score 1):

An other writable solution :

```
def block(X):
   n=X.size
   zeros=np.zeros((2*n-1,n),X.dtype)
   zeros[::2]=X
   return zeros.reshape(n,-1).T
```

try :

```
In [2]: %timeit block(X)
600 µs ± 33 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```